# Processing connecting ellipses with one line

Tags: java, processing

I am a beginner in Processing and have a question for a task I am trying to solve.

I have an array of two different ellipses, one red on the top of my screen and one of blue ellipses at the bottom. Now I am trying to draw lines from every blue ellipse to every red ellipse by just using one line.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my current code of the ellipses.

```
float x=50;
float yDown=height-50;
float yTop=height-550;
float radius=50;
KreisRot[] kreisRot = new KreisRot[width];
KreisBlau[] kreisBlau = new KreisBlau[width];

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);

  for (int r=0; r < kreisRot.length; r++) {
  kreisRot[r] = new KreisRot();
  }

  for (int b=0; b < kreisRot.length; b++) {
    kreisBlau[b] = new KreisBlau();
  }
}

void draw() {
  for (int r=0; r < kreisRot.length; r++) {

    kreisRot[r].showRed();
  }

  for (int b=0; b < kreisRot.length; b++) {

    kreisBlau[b].showBlue();
  }
}

class KreisBlau {
  float x=50;
  float yDown=height-50;
  float radius=50;

  void showBlue() {
    for (int b=0; b < kreisBlau.length; b++) {

      fill(0, 0, 255);
      ellipse(50+(b)*100, yDown, radius, radius);
    }
  }
}

class KreisRot {

  float x=50;
  float yTop=height-550;
  float radius=50;

  void showRed() {

    for (int r=0; r < kreisRot.length; r++) {

      fill(255, 0, 0);
      ellipse(50+(r)*100, yTop, radius, radius);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to create a single class `Kreis`, which has a [constructor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_constructors.htm), which can initialize the position and the color of the object. Further the class should have methods, to ask the object for ist x and y position (`X()`, `y()`):

```
class Kreis {
    float _x, _y;
    int  _r, _g, _b;
    float radius=50;

    Kreis(float x, float y, int r, int g, int b ) {
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
        this._r = r;
        this._g = g;
        this._b = b;
    }

    float X() { return _x; }
    float Y() { return _y; }

    void show() {
        fill(_r, _g, _b);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(_x, _y, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

Setup the objects like this:

```
Kreis[] kreisRot = new Kreis[6];
Kreis[] kreisBlau = new Kreis[6];

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);

    for (int r=0; r < kreisRot.length; r++) {
        kreisRot[r] = new Kreis(50+r*100, 50, 255, 0, 0);
    }

    for (int b=0; b < kreisRot.length; b++) {
        kreisBlau[b] = new Kreis(50+b*100, height-50, 0, 0, 255);
    }
}
```

To draw a line from each of the blue ellipses to each of the red ellipses, you need 2 nested loops. Get the position of the ellipses in the loop and draw a line between them:

```
void draw() {
    for (int r=0; r < kreisRot.length; r++) {
        kreisRot[r].show();
     }

    for (int b=0; b < kreisBlau.length; b++) {
        kreisBlau[b].show();
    }

    for (int r=0; r < kreisRot.length; r++) {
        for (int b=0; b < kreisBlau.length; b++) {
            stroke(0, 196, 0);
            strokeWeight(3);
            line(kreisRot[r].X(), kreisRot[r].Y(), kreisBlau[b].X(), kreisBlau[b].Y());
        }
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76 that made a little bit more sense, I am going to study your code.